# CSS issue with hypertext link on picture

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="container">
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/01.png"><img class="item2" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/1.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/02.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/2.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/03.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/3.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/04.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/4.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/05.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/5.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/06.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/6.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/07.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/7.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/08.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/8.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/09.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/9.png" /></a>
<a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/10.png"><img class="item1" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/10.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
#container { 
width:auto;
height:80%;
background: #eee; 
position:absolute; 
left: 50px; 
top:50px; 
bottom:50px; 
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; 
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item2 { height:96%; float:left; padding:0; margin:2%; -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; }
.item1 { height:46%; float:left; padding:0; margin:2%; -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; }
```

With the hypertext links, it [looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/)

The issue is that I don't manage to get the pictures being styled. The first one should be twice bigger than the others.

Without the hypertext links, it [looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/2/)
In that way, pictures look exactly how I would like. But I need the hypertext links to be added.

I guess my CSS is wrong because when the picture are like this `<a href=""><img src=""/></a>`, the CSS doesn't work. I tried `<p>`, `a.item2`, `img.item2 a` etc...

By the way, why is grey in the `#container` not covering all the div ?

Last issue : I made it responsive but from time to time, I have an one-pixel issue and then the second row of pictures disappears (it goes after the first row to the right).

Comment: um, I'm looking at the fiddle and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing that is wrong. Can you please explain: 1) what do you expect it to look like? 2) What are you seeing instead? (Note: don't reply in the comments, edit your question and add the info there as it should be a part of your question)

Comment: I expect it looks like the demo I've already posted after the CSS code part and instead, it looks like the demo I've already posted before the CSS code part.

Comment: In Stack Overflow - we expect the question to hang around forever. Your fiddle will disappear in a very short time... and your question should be complete in and of itself. ie you should be able to explain, in your question what you are expecting to see - I should not need to go to the fiddle in order to figure out what you want. Also - for all i know, your problem could be browser-specific and I could be seeing the same thing in both fiddles... for these reasons (and more besides), you should be able to explain to me... what you expect, and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: Now, as it turns out, I can replicate the problem by going to the working fiddle, and adding a span-tag around any one of your images... sop it looks like adding an inline (rather than block) level tag around your img is breaking things. That might help you solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to add a span-tag around the images, so it looks like that : `<a href=""><span><img class="item2" src="" /></span></a>`. It does'nt work... I presume I didn't exactly understand what you suggested to do...

Comment: No, you mistook what I was saying. I went to the *working* fiddle, and *broke* it (so it looks the same as the broken fiddle) by adding span-tags. ie it's nothing to do with the fact that you add links.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/14/)**

**CSS:**

```
a.item2 {
    height:96%;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:2%;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
a.item1 {
    height:46%;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:2%;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"> 
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/01.png" class="item2"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/1.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/02.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/2.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/03.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/3.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/04.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/4.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/05.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/5.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/06.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/6.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/07.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/7.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/08.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/8.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/09.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/9.png" /></a>
 <a href="http://arkhana.fr/img/10.png" class="item1"><img src="http://arkhana.fr/img/10.png" /></a>

</div>
```

Hope this is what you want..

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to keep the aspect ratio of the pictures. As it is, each picture is resizable. I would like the pictures to be squares (item2 twice bigger than item1).

Comment: Then you can use max-width/height for image instead of width/height

Answer (score 0):

I changed in fiddle. I added new class and added it to  
[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/)

```
 .link{
    height: 50%;
}

.item1 { height:99%; float:left; padding:0; margin:2%; -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; }

<a  href="http://arkhana.fr/img/01.png"><img class="item2" src="http://arkhana.fr/img/1.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesn't seem to be the good link to the code... So I can't get what `.link` is about...

Comment: exactly the same reason why you need to not put your info in a fiddle for your question too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One line of Tweak without changing HTML or adding class

```
#container a:nth-child(1){
    height: 96%;
    display: flex;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a.item2 {
height:96%;
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:2%;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
}

a.item1 {
height:46%;
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:2% 2% 2% 0;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
}

img {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

add

```
 #container{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: ...and yet you haven't told us yet what a working solution is supposed to look like...

Comment: ... And the answer to this question was in my very first post : there were two demos, one is for what It is supposed to look like and one is the issue with hypertext links. As you told me to be more explicit, I edited my post and I re-explained what I was looking for and how it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your css file. Since is not taking any height thats why image is not showing as its in percentage.

```
#container{overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this Demo it may help you
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/19/)

```
a.aitem1
{
  height:46%;
}
```

### check this

[another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/23/)

Comment: you want to make it resposive

Comment: In the first demo in my post, it is responsive.

Comment: please share the here again i cannot find it

Comment: Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/2/ - I would like the exact same looking but with hypertext links on pictures. My problem is that the pictures are not styled anymore when I add links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLgg4v1e/21/)** with some css changes.

**Updated Css:**

```
#container { 
width:auto;
height:80%;
background: #eee; 
position:absolute; 
left: 50px; 
top:50px; 
bottom:50px; 
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; 
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container a {display: flex; margin:2%;  -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; height:46%;}
#container a:first-child {height:96%;flex-direction: initial;}
#container a img { padding:0; margin:0; max-width:100%; max-height:100%; }
```